# How to do a Postgresql subquery in select clause with join

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
select date(datetime) as dates,
        user_id,
        sum(CASE When status='completed' Then 1 Else 0 End ) as completed,
        sum(CASE When status='incompleted' Then 1 Else 0 End ) as incompleted,
        sum(CASE When status!='' Then 1 Else 0 End ) as total 
from routine_streak 
where user_id ='"+user_id+"' 
and datetime  between '"+start+"' and '"+end+"' 
group by user_id,date(datetime)
```

I want join to join theses two tables:

I have two table one is quick and another is streak i have to get wayname from another table(streak) using profile field and id I want use join to get wayname from quick table in streaktable  in postgresql query...

here is my table:quick

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS quick(
   id integer DEFAULT nextval('quick_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
   profile integer NOT NULL,
   wayname character varying NOT NULL,
   datetime timestamp without time zone NULL,
);
```

second table :streak

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS streak(
id integer DEFAULT nextval('streak_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
user_id integer NOT NULL,
wayid integer NOT NULL,
status character varying(50)  DEFAULT NULL::character varying NULL,
day character varying(50)  DEFAULT NULL::character varying NULL,
streak character varying(50)  DEFAULT NULL::character varying NULL,
datetime timestamp without time zone NULL,
CONSTRAINT "routine_streak_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

);

output should be like:

```
user_id:11,
wayname:abc,
way_id:12,
dates: 2019-01-30,
completed: 1
incompleted: 1,
total: 2
```

Comment: Where's the query you tried?  Add some sample rows from the table? Your output does not look like a  result of a join. Tell us correctly what you truly want.

Comment: select date(datetime) as dates,
        user_id,
        sum(CASE When status='completed' Then 1 Else 0 End ) as completed,
        sum(CASE When status='incompleted' Then 1 Else 0 End ) as incompleted,
        sum(CASE When status!='' Then 1 Else 0 End ) as total 
from routine_streak 
where user_id ='"+user_id+"' 
and datetime  between '"+start+"' and '"+end+"' 
group by user_id,date(datetime)

Answer (score 0):

If the id in quick is a primary key, then normal join will do the trick.

```
select
    q.wayname
    , date(s.datetime) as dates, user_id, sum(CASE When status='completed' Then 1 Else 0 End ) as completed, sum(CASE When status='incompleted' Then 1 Else 0 End ) as incompleted, sum(CASE When status!='' Then 1 Else 0 End ) as total
    from routine_streak s
    join quick q on s.user_id = q.id
    where user_id ='"+user_id+"' and datetime between '"+start+"' and '"+end+"'
    group by user_id,date(datetime), q.wayname
```

Or, you prefer to use subquery, then

```
select
    (select wayname from quick q where s.user_id = q.id) wayname
    , *
from ( #{your query goes here} ) s
```

Comment: Sure, you can give it a try

Comment: yes, query is running but it is not showing any record

Comment: It can show records before ?! emn... Try the second one.

Comment: could you implement left join in query because it shows all name data